# How to remove charset=utf-8 from content type in response header

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, response-headers

Here is my code :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] JObject jobject)
{
    JObject changedObject = new JObject();
    if (jobject.ContainsKey("name"))
    {
        changedObject.Add("id", "1");
        changedObject.Add("name", jobject.GetValue("name"));
        changedObject.Add("employment", "private");
    }

    Response.ContentType= "application/json";
    return Ok(changedObject);
}
```

This result returns `Content-Type "application/json; charset=utf-8"`.

How can I have response header `content-type = "application/json"`?

Comment: But why though? `System.Text.Json` serialises as utf8. What do you expect to happen if the name contains `'﷽'`?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? ASP.NET Core? Something else that follows a similar pattern?

Comment: @Llama , this is ASP.NET but with newtonsoft json dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning

```
return Ok(changedObject);
```

returned:

```
 return Json(changedObject).
```

and it worked.